# awk to skip pattern and compare lines and output match and mismatch between files

Tags: awk

In the below `awk` I am skipping the lines that start with `#` and trying to find the matching lines between two files based on 4 specific columns, and if a line does not match it outputs the file and line it is missing from. Thank you :).

**file1**

```
##....
#....
chr1    1013466 .   T   TA  11438.1 PASS
chr1    1013490 .   C   G   14137   PASS
chr1    1013600 .   T   TAA 1140    PASS
```

**file2**

```
##...
#....
chr1    1013466 .   T   TA  10914   PASS
chr1    1013490 .   C   G   13785.1 PASS
chr1    1014600 .   C   A   2000    PASS
```

**awk**

```
f1=1234.txt
f2=5678.txt
awk -F'\t' '/^[^#]/ FNR==1 { next }
   FNR == NR { $f1[$1,$2,$4,$5] = $1 FS $2 FS $4 FS $5 }
   FNR != NR { $f2[$1,$2,$4,$5] = $1 FS $2 FS $4 FS $5 }
         END { print "Match:"; for (k in $f1) if (k in $f2) print $f1[k] # Or $f2[k]
         print "Not Found:"; for (k in $f2) if (!(k in $f1)) print $f2[k]
}' OFS="\t" $f1 $f2
```

**desired** `tab-delimited`

```
Match between 1234.txt and 5678.txt:
chr1    1013466 .   T   TA  11438.1 PASS
chr1    1013490 .   C   G   14137   PASS
Not Found in 1234.txt:
chr1    1014600 .   C   A   2000    PASS
Not Found in 5678.txt:
chr1    1013600 .   T   TAA 1140    PASS
```

Comment: if you can convince the files to to sort then looks like a job for `comm`

Comment: within a given file is it possible for the 4 columns of interest (1,2,5,6) to have duplicates?

Comment: This file type (VCF file) is specific to bioinformatics @markp-fuso; the VCF format specification (https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/VCFv4.2.pdf) states that each line is a unique variant identified using chromosome ($1), position ($2), reference base/s ($4), and alternate base/s ($5), however each of the individual columns can/will have duplicates i.e. all lines in this example refer to variants on the same chromosome ($1 == "chr1").

Comment: @tomc `comm` alone couldn't handle only comparing a subset of fields in each line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few issues:

- the incorrect prefacing of `awk` variables with a `$`; in `awk` the `$` is used to preface column references but *not* variable references
- need to capture the entire input line (not just the 4 index columns)
- the missing set of logic for the 3rd set of data
- need to capture the input filenames (to be included in the output headers)

One `awk` idea:

```
f1=1234.txt
f2=5678.txt

awk '
BEGIN     { FS=OFS="\t" }
/^#/      { next }
          { ndx=$1 FS $2 FS $4 FS $5 }
FNR == NR { if (!fname1) fname1=FILENAME; f1[ndx]=$0 }
FNR != NR { if (!fname2) fname2=FILENAME; f2[ndx]=$0 }
END       { printf "Match between %s and %s:\n", fname1, fname2                
            for (ndx in f1)
                if (ndx in f2)
                   print f1[ndx]

            printf "Not Found in %s:\n",fname1
            for (ndx in f2)
                if ( !(ndx in f1) )
                   print f2[ndx]

            printf "Not Found in %s:\n",fname2
            for (ndx in f1)
                if ( !(ndx in f2) )
                   print f1[ndx]
          }
' $f1 $f2
```

This generates:

```
Match between 1234.txt and 5678.txt:
chr1    1013490 .   C   G   14137   PASS
chr1    1013466 .   T   TA  11438.1 PASS
Not Found in 1234.txt:
chr1    1014600 .   C   A   2000    PASS
Not Found in 5678.txt:
chr1    1013600 .   T   TAA 1140    PASS
```

---

If it's necessary to maintain the input ordering of the rows:

```
awk '
BEGIN     { FS=OFS="\t" }
/^#/      { next }
          { ndx=$1 FS $2 FS $4 FS $5 }
FNR == NR { if (!fname1) fname1=FILENAME; indices1[++cnt1]=ndx; f1[ndx]=$0 }
FNR != NR { if (!fname2) fname2=FILENAME; indices2[++cnt2]=ndx; f2[ndx]=$0 }

END       { printf "Match between %s and %s:\n", fname1, fname2
            for (i=1;i<=cnt1;i++) {
                ndx=indices1[i]
                if (ndx in f1 && ndx in f2)
                   print f1[ndx]
            }

            printf "Not Found in %s:\n",fname1
            for (i=1;i<=cnt2;i++) {
                ndx=indices2[i]
                if ( !(ndx in f1) )
                   print f2[ndx]
            }

            printf "Not Found in %s:\n",fname2
            for (i=1;i<=cnt1;i++) {
                ndx=indices1[i]
                if ( !(ndx in f2) )
                   print f1[ndx]
            }
          }
' $f1 $f2
```

This generates:

```
Match between 1234.txt and 5678.txt:
chr1    1013466 .   T   TA  11438.1 PASS
chr1    1013490 .   C   G   14137   PASS
Not Found in 1234.txt:
chr1    1014600 .   C   A   2000    PASS
Not Found in 5678.txt:
chr1    1013600 .   T   TAA 1140    PASS
```

Comment: +1 Nice solution in my view, neater than the attempt I finally got working (nested loops, `if(ind in array)` as you have used is much better). I was able to dispense with setting the field separators as they are not needed for the comparisons (where the default space will do) and, without a reset, $0 is passed unchanged to print (so if it had `\t` to begin with it will keep it).

Comment: Thank you both for the nice solutions :).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming each key is unique in each input file and you don't are about the order of lines per file in the output:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
/^#/ { next }
{ key = $1 FS $2 FS $4 FS $5 }
NR==FNR {
    file1[key] = $0
    next
}
{
    if ( key in file1 ) {
        both[key] = file1[key]
        delete file1[key]
    }
    else {
        file2[key] = $0
    }
}
END {
    printf "Match between %s and %s\n", ARGV[1], ARGV[2]
    for ( key in both ) {
        print both[key]
    }
    printf "Not found in %s\n", ARGV[1]
    for ( key in file2 ) {
        print file2[key]
    }
    printf "Not found in %s\n", ARGV[2]
    for ( key in file1 ) {
        print file1[key]
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk 1234.txt 5678.txt
Match between 1234.txt and 5678.txt
chr1    1013466 .       T       TA      11438.1 PASS
chr1    1013490 .       C       G       14137   PASS
Not found in 1234.txt
chr1    1014600 .       C       A       2000    PASS
Not found in 5678.txt
chr1    1013600 .       T       TAA     1140    PASS
```

Comment: +1 Clever way to accumulate & filter the comparison fields and their associated records. When I first ran this is failed. I debugged and got it working by deleting the BEGIN block. It turned out the short last tab in `chr1    1013490 .   C   G   13785.1 PASS` of 5678.txt in my copy (pasted from Q) was replaced with a space (at least tabbing from the previous char jumped 2 tabs), causing it to fail. I don't see any purpose for setting the OFS as I thought printing $0 simply passes the intact record to output. Also the default FS <blank> produces the same fields whether tabs or spaces are read.

Comment: @DavePritlove Using the default FS would fail if the OPs real data can ever have empty fields or fields that contain blanks. Since they use tab for FS and OFS, I did the same but setting OFS isn't necessary.